# WFS harvesting GeoNetwork 3.2.2

Tags: wfs, query, geonetwork, getfeature

I'm having an issue harvesting a WFS (GetFeature) endpoint using GeoNetwork.
I can hit the endpoint through the browser so I know that's fine.

When I create the harvester I enter in the "Service URL" as the "GetFeature" endpoint. Then for the "OGC WFS GetFeature Query" I have been entering this XML

```
<wfs:GetFeature 
  service="WFS" 
  version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
<wfs:Query typeName="XXXXXXXXXX"/>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

This is where everything seems to go wrong, I get one of two results, depending on me changing between different XML code, not submitting a query or submitting the key pairs as string.

There is a red "!" that appears in the top left corner and an unhelpful java message down the bottom of the form.

Or an error message that tells me my XML is unable to parse, and wipes my Query.

Has anyone encountered this before ?

Perhaps it is a known bug, or a user error.

Comment: what is your xml content and the error details?

Comment: This is the XML

<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">

<wfs:Query typeName="XXXXXXXXXX"/>

</wfs:GetFeature>


and the error message that tells me my XML is unable to parse, and wipes my Query.

Comment: Are you using the API or GUI?

Comment: What is your XML query? It doesn't appear on your question. Most likely, it is wrong or uses some incompatible extension with the WFS server you are trying to reach.

Remember that you don't need you fill a query unless you want to filter the results.